# RandomForestRegressor leads to KeyError: 'squared_error'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to predict house prices in the Cali housing data set with a random forest. I do not understand why I get a `KeyError: 'squared_error'` in this simple code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import sklearn.ensemble

housing = fetch_california_housing()
rfr = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,
                       max_depth=int(25),
                       max_features="auto",
                       n_jobs=-1,
                       oob_score = True,
                       min_samples_leaf=20,
                       criterion = 'squared_error')

rfr.fit(housing.data, housing.target)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 387, in fit
    trees = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1054, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 933, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 595, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 222, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 169, in _parallel_build_trees
    tree.fit(X, y, sample_weight=curr_sample_weight, check_input=False)
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py", line 1247, in fit
    super().fit(
  File "/home/kratz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py", line 350, in fit
    criterion = CRITERIA_REG[self.criterion](self.n_outputs_,
KeyError: 'squared_error'
```

Comment: Can you check your sci-kit version using `pip freeze`? If it's prior to version 1.0 you should use `criterion="mse"`

Comment: @Japsz The scikit-learn version is 0.24.1.

Comment: @Japsz Indeed that solved it! Thanks. Cannot accept the answer because that's a comment but yes, this was apparently the reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably due to the version of `scikit-learn` in your environment. According to the [docs for RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) `criterion = 'squared_error'` was introduced in v1.0, so if you have a prior version use `criterion='mse'` instead.

You can use `pip freeze` to check for the version of your libraries in your env; for scikit-learn you can also use:

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```